# Java: Accessing Memory Objects, Members, and Information in Computer's memory (With Reflection?)

Tags: java, memory, reflection, memory-address

Dr. Gamut's Comment:

> "Here's the memory locations of the string data of items for sale and purchase history, the offsets in bold are the only ones that need to be adjusted. For sale: [[[[[[[ffxiv.exe+F8EBE0]+20]+18]+84]+20]+32C]] Price +0 Total +4 Quantity +8 Town +C Retainer +10 Next Item Price +14 Purchase history [[[[[[[ffxiv.exe+F8EBE0]+20]+1C]+84]+20]+AFC]] Price +0 Quantity +4 Buyer +8 Time +C Next Item Price +14 I'm going to work on my own standalone application for private use, but integrating a feature like this into your program which is already widely used and trusted could really benefit the community."

I want to access this memory location using Java. I'm creating a FFXIV Market Analyzer and can so far: - Receive Input for an Item (Name, Description, Personal Notes, Components of this Item, Items this is a component of, Current Prices and Historical Prices based on High/Regular Quality) - Save and Load said Input from a Data File. - Analyze data to give you the average current individual price, quantity, and total gil price. - Analyze data to give you the average historical individual price, quantity, total gil price, average time between purchases, and average gil traded per hour. There is no problem with the tools for analyzation, but getting the info is tedious and repetitive. How can I access this memory so that the input system becomes automated?

I heard that Reflection can give me an object and it's members, but how do I access memory from the main computer?

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is used to get references to Class, Method and Constructor objects (among others).  Essentially you are accessing meta-data about loaded classes.  It is not used for retrieving data from memory or disk.

Answer (score 0):

You don't access the main memory. You cannot do this with Java and most operating system will forbid it anyway, no matter which language. It would be a big security issue if you could just "access" some memory.

And: No matter what you want to do, accessing "some memory" is a pretty bad idea. Languages like Java are made to hide things like - because it is a bad idea. Sometimes you must access memory addresses, like when you develop a driver or some operating system facilities. Maybe for other hardware dependent task. But I think in your case (collecting some price data of something) it the completely wrong way.

And by the way, who is Dr. Gamut?

Comment: I was on a reddit forum where we were speaking about a Final Fantasy XIV API was created and allowed you to access virtually everything BUT the market data. It was extremely expansive and the community was upset that we didn't get a market API. So a so called "Dr. Gamut", who is probably a regular user rather than an actual doctor, told me the memory positions of the market data.

Comment: Maybe you could link the Reddit conversation?